# Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc

Olá. Após horas tentando resolver este problema e pesquisas que fiz sobre o problema, vim lhes perguntar como posso sanar esta questão

O erro é:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /home/iaulas/public_html/system/application/models/site_model.php on line 483

Removi a linha referente ao erro para ver se este erro ocorria em algum outro local e em outra linha ocorre o mesmo erro.

Esta é a função: (Utilizo do framework codeigniter)

```
        function cat_busca() { 
        $query = 'SELECT materiais_cat_id as id, MCCat as cat, MCOrdem as ordem FROM ((SELECT * FROM materiais_cat where materiais_cat.MCMostrar = "Sim" GROUP BY MCCat) UNION (SELECT * FROM livros_cat WHERE livros_cat.LCMostrar = "Sim" GROUP BY LCCat) UNION (SELECT * FROM cursos_cat WHERE cursos_cat.CCMostrar = "Sim" GROUP BY CCCat)) AS tabela ORDER BY ordem';
        $retorno = $this->db->query($query);
        return $retorno->result();
    }
```

Não consegui postar o código todo, pois são quase 4 mil linhas.

Além de ajuda para corrigir, gostaria de entender o porque deste erro ocorrer, pois passou a acontecer somente após de eu mudar o site de hospedagem.

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro é causado pela sua linha de comando `SQL` que está na variável `$query`. Já passei várias vezes por esse problema até fazer com que me retornasse se existia uma linha pelo menos dessa consulta.

Para você não passar esse tipo de problema é aconselhavel que você sempre verifique o número de linhas retornadas, assim deixando seu código:

```
function cat_busca() { 
        $query = 'SELECT materiais_cat_id as id, MCCat as cat, MCOrdem as ordem FROM ((SELECT * FROM materiais_cat where materiais_cat.MCMostrar = "Sim" GROUP BY MCCat) UNION (SELECT * FROM livros_cat WHERE livros_cat.LCMostrar = "Sim" GROUP BY LCCat) UNION (SELECT * FROM cursos_cat WHERE cursos_cat.CCMostrar = "Sim" GROUP BY CCCat)) AS tabela ORDER BY ordem';
        $retorno = $this->db->query($query);
if($retorno->num_rows() > 0){
        return $retorno->result();
}else{
return false;
}
}
```

O erro

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in
>   /home/iaulas/public_html/system/application/models/site_model.php on
>   line 483

quer dizer que a função que você chama **result()** não é um objeto, ou seja, não tem nenhum registro e você está obrigando a ele imprimir um objeto que não tem.

Sempre faça a verificação de número de linhas para ver se retornou alguma. Se você acha que esse erro é estranho e que teria que retornar algo, então verifique o seu comando `SQL` da **$query**, talvez o erro esteja ai.